# Convert.TryToInt64 instead of Convert.ToInt64?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, performance

I have [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd730022.aspx) function I have to implement:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
    Object value,
    ValidationContext validationContext
)
{
  //Here is where I wanna test whether the following conversion is applicable
  var x = Convert.ToInt64(value);
}
```

I could wrap that line in a try-catch block, or with other ways to perform that test, here is one of them:

```
var convertible = value as IConvertible;
if (convertible != null)
  var x = convertible.ToInt64(null);
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here you can define a default value, if the parse (conversion) is applicable it will return the converted int64 otherwise the default value will be returned:

```
Int64 DefaultValue = 0;
Int64.TryParse(MyVar , out DefaultValue);
```

ie:

```
Int64 DefaultValue = 0;
Int64.TryParse("1234" , out DefaultValue);
```

DefaultValue will be 1234

```
Int64 DefaultValue = 0;
 Int64.TryParse("test" , out DefaultValue);
```

DefaultValue will be 0

You can also make it even shrorter by declaring the variable like this:

```
 Int64.TryParse("123" , out Int64 DefaultValue);
```

Comment: `TryParse` returns a boolean, you are not passing a default value you are passing the actual variable.

Comment: you are absolutely right, its 5:50 in the morning in here, when you stay up till now these things happen ;). thanks for correcting me.

Comment: I didn't test it, but I think I'll use the `IConvertible` option suggested in the original question. much cleaner and also converting value to string doesn't make sense at all. The expected value should be a numberic value (int, short, decimal etc.), I want to validate that it's not equal to zero.

Comment: i think there is a misunderstanding here, these were examples that were trying to convert string to int64 (if applicable). you can use **null** for instance.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, both string and int implement IConvertible :)

Comment: var ok = Int64.TryParse( v, out long l );

Answer (score 1):

Using `IConvertible` worked best for me.

I've made a short test and this way was WAY (6 times) quicker, using `IConvertible`, the code also looks cleaner and less verbose to my taste.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var sw = new Stopwatch();

  sw.Start();
  for (short i = 0; i < short.MaxValue; i++)
  {
    var foo = IsValid1(i);
  }
  sw.Stop();
  var result1 = sw.Elapsed;
  Console.WriteLine(result1);

  sw.Start();
  for (short i = 0; i < short.MaxValue; i++)
  {
    var foo = IsValid2(i);
  }
  sw.Stop();
  var result2 = sw.Elapsed;

  Console.WriteLine(result2);
  Console.ReadKey();
}

static bool IsValid1(object value)
{
  var convertible = value as IConvertible;
  if (convertible != null)
    return convertible.ToInt64(null) != 0;
  return true;
}
static bool IsValid2(object value)
{
  if (value != null)
  {
    long amount;
    if (long.TryParse(value.ToString(), out amount))
      return amount != 0;
  }
  return true;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
00:00:00.0031987
00:00:00.0186700
```

Comment: This still doesn't guarantee that it will succeed. Any of the `To` functions can throw an `InvalidCastException` if they cannot do the conversion.

Comment: @siride, wrong. the [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx#languageReferenceRemarksToggle) operator is a conditional cast that returns null if cast fails, as opposed to the cast operator that throws on failure.

Comment: that's not the part I'm talking about. I don't doubt that the cast to IConvertible works. I'm talking about the call to `ToInt64`. That could very well fail with an exception. That should have been clear from my initial comment where I specifically mentioned that the `To` functions can fail with an exception.

Comment: @siride, I get your point. In my particular case I only expect numeric values to get here. but you're right. I'll leave this answer here for people to know about the `IConvertible` and its performance benifits compare to other methods.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Int64.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.tryparse.aspx)?  Of course you would need to `.ToString()` your `value` param, otherwise I would think this would work.